# Conflicting types and casting in C

Tags: c, types, casting

This is probably a simple question for you to figure out I am just having some trouble with my getAverage function, it returns a float variable type. I keep getting a "Conflicting Types" error message at the line 114, where my function is located. I am not sure if my syntax is wrong for my method or what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my function:

```
float getAverage(int nume, int deno)
{
    float average;
    average = (float)(nume/deno);
    return average;
}
```

Edit: My function is below my main function.

Comment: You might wanna do ((float)nume/deno) to actually do type-casting

Comment: I am still getting a conflicting types error even after trying that. I am still learning C so im sure once I figure it out I will have to slap myself haha.

Comment: @UnderDog Agree.  Could even use `average = (float)(((double)nume)/deno);` for more precision with large `int` values.

Comment: You need to move the float cast to avoid doing integer division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call your function before it is declared the compiler will assume it returns an `int`.  As your function returns a `float` you would get a `conflicting types` error.

Comment: Ahhh thank you that fixed my problem I did not know that the compiler assumes int unless you pre-declare the function. Thank you!